# Change Url to accept a string instead id in phoenix framework (elixir)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to implement permalinks in phoenix app.

The goal is to change localhost:4000/products/1 to localhost:4000/products/productname

I tried following Ryan Bates episode on [permalinks implementation in rails](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url?autoplay=true)
but wasn't able to find a to_param function for models in phoenix.

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for but here you go:

router.ex in the browser stack

```
get "/products/:product_name", ProductController, :get_product_by_name
```

product_controller.ex

```
def get_product_by_name(conn, %{"product_name" => product_name}) do
  product = Repo.get_by(Product, name: product_name)
  render(conn, "product_info.html", product)
end
```

That should be all you need if you want your application to return a specific product based on name as a html page, naturally you will need to have a html page with the name "product_info.html.eex" under templates/product

Answer (score 22):

In addition to Wobbley's response, `to_param` in Phoenix is implemented with protocols. For example, here is how you could change how the URLs for products are generated:

```
defimpl Phoenix.Param, for: MyApp.Product do
  def to_param(%{name: name}) do
    "#{name}"
  end
end
```

A more complex example is also shown on [Programming Phoenix](https://pragprog.com/book/phoenix/programming-phoenix) (disclaimer: I am one of the authors).

Comment: But the restful routes generated by phoenix(v1.2.rc) still use :id as default param name, you need use explicit set param. e.g `resources "/users", UserController, param: "name"`

Comment: Also, take a look at the docs: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Param.html. This protocol is derivable, so adding `@derive {Phoenix.Param, key: :product_name}` on your model before the `schema` call should suffice to generate seo-friendly urls without modifying your templates (only how you retrieve the records in the controller).

Comment: In the event that someone wanted to modify the struct key in some way (say, downcasing the `product_name`) they would have to use the longer `defimpl` version to be able to call a function, correct?