# Looking up records by a field other than primary key

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

In Ecto I can easily do this:

```
Repo.get!(Kaderi.Forum, params["id"])
```

To look up a record by primary key, which by default is `id`.

However I'm looking at implementing pretty URLs with a slug instead of an ID. I have a `slug` field in my model and I can easily use it to generate URLs in Phoenix like so:

```
defmodule Kaderi.Forum do
  use Kaderi.Web, :model

  @derive {Phoenix.Param, key: :slug}
  ...
```

But there doesn't seem to be a simple way of automatically looking up records by the `slug` field.

I *can* do something like the following:

```
Repo.get_by!(Kaderi.Forum, slug: params["id"])
```

But it seems like there should be some nice way of configuring it in the model, so that I can automatically generate URLs to, and then lookup records by slugs without having to touch the controller. If I change how I generate pretty URLs in the future, I shouldn't have to go update the controller again.

Is there some neat Ecto/Phoenix trick I'm missing to do this easily?

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand what the "ideal" solution you wish to achieve is, but what's wrong with using get _by? Is a solution you are happy with in any way similar to this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570612/change-url-to-accept-a-string-instead-id-in-phoenix-framework-elixir/34570728#34570728

Comment: @Wobbley The ideal solution would be a line of code to configure the model to look up records by slug, instead of id. I don't have to change my views to render links using the slug, so it seems a little odd that I have to change my controller to use them.

Comment: Basically I know that the lookup by `id` isnt hardcoded, because if you change the primary key in the model it will use that instead. I don't know if the primary key part is also hardcoded, or can be configured.

Comment: @sevenseacat the primary_key part is hard-coded based on the struct https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/3c5d052688194786f3532d7a0593e8c6177e1727/lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex#L187 The Programming Phoenix book covers using a custom Ecto Type http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Type.html as the primary key with a slug. It includes the id in the slug, such as "13-overriding-primary-key" and is very similar to the example in the Ecto.Type docs.

Comment: Bah, I was hoping that wasn't the case.

Comment: I'm with you @sevenseacat. I wanted to be able to create URL helpers and path helpers using the slug/permalink!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this if your slug includes the id (as in `3-my-page` instead of just `my-page`.)

This is an example from the [Ecto.Type](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Type.html) documentation copied here for convenience:

```
defmodule Permalink do
  @behaviour Ecto.Type
  def type, do: :integer

  # Provide our own casting rules.
  def cast(string) when is_binary(string) do
    case Integer.parse(string) do
      {int, _} -> {:ok, int}
      :error   -> :error
    end
  end

  # We should still accept integers
  def cast(integer) when is_integer(integer), do: {:ok, integer}

  # Everything else is a failure though
  def cast(_), do: :error

  # When loading data from the database, we are guaranteed to
  # receive an integer (as databases are strict) and we will
  # just return it to be stored in the model struct.
  def load(integer) when is_integer(integer), do: {:ok, integer}

  # When dumping data to the database, we *expect* an integer
  # but any value could be inserted into the struct, so we need
  # guard against them.
  def dump(integer) when is_integer(integer), do: {:ok, integer}
  def dump(_), do: :error
end
```

You can then override the primary key for your schema:

```
defmodule Post do
  use Ecto.Schema

  @primary_key {:id, Permalink, autogenerate: true}
  schema "posts" do
    ...
  end
end
```

Now when you call `Repo.get(Page, "3-my-page")` the string "3-my-page" will be cast to the integer 3 (which is the primary key for the model) and the page will be returned.

If you don't have the integer in your slug then there is currently no simple way to do this, you would be best to continue using `Repo.get_by`.