# Url to accept string instead of Id with spaces

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Someone asked this question in the past, and I even answered it [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570612/change-url-to-accept-a-string-instead-id-in-phoenix-framework-elixir/34570728#34570728).
However with upgrading to 1.1.2, this approach no longer works. As any white-space in the name such as "Super Cleaner" is now represented as "Super+Cleaner" and this is the value passed into the query, hence receiving no hits. What is the proper way to do this? I assume it has something to do with Phoenix.Param as Valim answered in the other post? The problem boils down to that it is treated as an integer instead of a string, and I have no idea why.

How it is: http://localhost:4000/weapons/Super+Cleaner

How it should be: http://localhost:4000/weapons/Super%20Cleaner

EDIT: Updated to include my code

**HTML**

```
<a class="secondary button" href="<%= weapon_path(@conn, :html_weapon_info, weapon.name) %>">Weapon Details</a>
```

**Router**

```
get "/weapons/:weapon_name", WeaponController, :html_weapon_info
```

**Controller**

```
def html_weapon_info(conn, %{"weapon_name" => weapon_name}) do
  weapon = Repo.get_by(Weapon, name: weapon_name)
  ships = Weapon |> Weapon.get_ships(weapon_name) |> Repo.all
  render(conn, "weapon_show.html", weapon: weapon, ships: ships)
end
```

My problem is that the weapon_name has the value "Super+Cleaner" now, making the query return no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution to this is a combination of both yours and José's answer to the question you linked to. Here's a quick recap:

#### 1. Implement the `Phoenix.Param` protocol for your model

This tells Phoenix which attribute to put in the URL when rendering URLs for your model.

```
# web/models/weapon.ex
defmodule MyApp.Weapon do
  # ...

  defimpl Phoenix.Param do
    def to_param(%{name: name}) do
      to_string(name)
    end
  end
end
```

#### 2. Adjust the param name in the router

This step is optional, but if the parameter contains the name instead of an id, it should be called that way in my opinion.

```
# web/router.ex

resources "/weapons", WeaponController, param: "name"
```

#### 3. Adjust controller to fetch records by new param

As we don't pass the ID any more in the URL, we need to adjust the queries in the controller for the show/edit/update/delete actions to fetch the weapons by name instead of ID:

```
# web/controllers/weapon_controller.ex

weapon = Repo.get_by!(Weapon, name: name)
```

---

Finally, the thing with the spaces seems to be a completely different issue. The plus-encoded spaces are coming from a  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding. However this type of encoding is only valid within the query component, but not as part of the URL itself. You're absolutely correct that spaces should be encoded as `%20` instead which means that you've probably found a bug in Phoenix!

Comment: Filed a bug with Phoenix here: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1616

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have to admit I am still not sure how Param helps me here as I am pretty new to Phoenix and Elixir. I guess I am approaching it wrong as I am sending the name manually in the HTML and not through built in Phoenix functions? I am not using the resources on purpose as I only want a get. I updated my comment to include the code. Thanks for the great reply :)

Comment: Hey @Wobbley, what you did looks absolutely fine. You can achieve the same effect with `resources` and the `only: [:get]` option, but that's just a convenience wrapper to do the same thing. The params protocol is important when you render your URL in the view. E.g. when you generate a link to the "show" page of the weapon, you call `weapon_path(@conn, :show, weapon)` and then phoenix uses the params protocol to figure out which attribute of the weapon to put at the end of the url.

Comment: The PR is out, let's hope this can be resolved quickly ;-) https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/pull/1617

Comment: I see, I guess I should rather create a "default" method that retrieves based on name instead of the "custom" one I made. Thanks for the PR :)

Comment: That would be a good idea because you would not leak the details about the URL param into the view, just put in the weapon and the URL will be correct. Also makes it easier to change the param later. However, the method you used to generate the URL should still give you the correct result.