# Ecto+Phoenix: How to make resource paths with a different key than :id?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an application where resources are saved in the database by a normal ID. However, to prevent database enumeration, the IDs that are shown to the users in paths and links are UUID-like. (An example: http://example.com/payment/yta6Bo34s)

To create normal, id-based links in Phoenix+Ecto, one can just do:

`link to: payment_path(@conn, :show, payment)`

However, this implicitly uses the `.id` field of the `%Payment{}` struct that is passed here.

When using an UUID, one has to do

`link to: payment_path(@conn, :show, payment.uuid)`

or, in the case of my application where the UUIDs are saved as bigints in the database, but shown as base36-strings:

`link to: payment_path(@conn, :show, UUID.encode(payment.uuid))`

Is there a way to streamline this process? For instance, is there a protocol that can be implemented for structs passed to the Phoenix path helpers, so they'll automatically use a custom procedure to generate show/edit/update/delete paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could implement `to_param` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570612/change-url-to-accept-a-string-instead-id-in-phoenix-framework-elixir) or the derive form as described [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Param.html#to_param/1).